# I have three tables. i need to perform a join

Tags: linq

Table 1
RollNo
Name

Table 2
SubjectId
SubjectName

Table 3 (Mapping table for 1 and 2)
RollNo
SubjectId

I need a linq statement to join all three statements where I can get subject name along with table 1 details

Expected Result

Roll no  Name  Subjects

1            Abc      Maths

1            Abc      Science

2            Xyz       Maths

Comment: Have you tried something already? What didn't work?

Comment: First, I joined table 1 and 3, then I joined 2 and 3
Then i need to join the above two results. 
I want to perform in one single query

Comment: Yeah, it's not even clear in which environment you're working. Which type of LINQ, mappings, classes, database, ... Also, you're not the first one trying to query many-to-many associations. You should be able to find *similar* cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var data= ( from t1 in table1 join t3 in table3 on t1.RollNo equals t3.RollNo 
                               join t2 in table2 on t3.SubjectId equals t2.SubjectId

 select new datadto{ Name = t1.Name, SubjectName= t2.SubjectName}).ToArray()
```

Comment: I will be getting a list of subjects from table 2, because one student may select more than one subject

Comment: Yes you are right
I have edited the question
Please refer to question

Comment: as per ur result u can take my code that works...and use orderby by Name...and i hope u know wt is datadto and declare variable Rollno ..assigned the value in linq